# Does webpack compile Angular2 typescript to javascript?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have followed Angular2 tutorial to add webpack. I get following errors e.g.:

```
    [default] D:\...\node_modules\@angular\core\src\util\decorators.d.ts:11:4 
Property 'extends' of type 'Type<any> | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'Function | any[] | Type<any>'.[default] D:\...\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\dom\dom_renderer.d.ts:25:21
```

It seems that webpack tries to compile the whole angular stuff that I reference, which seems a bit too much.

As far as I understand there are already built angular js files that we can use instead of compiling angular (and all other libraries I suppose) each time? Is it possible/reasonable to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does whatever you include and tell it to do.

E.g. if you directly import an angular typescript file from your main module (or anything that is included from it) and if you have a loader for typescript configured it will transpile this typescript to javascript.

However if you import a javascript module (like with `import { Component } from '@angular/core'`. No trailing `.ts`) it will include that and not transpile anything.;

Your error could also be some problem with type definitions. Which means it already uses the javascript version, but there's somehow a problem with the configured/referenced typescript typings (`.d.ts` is mentioned) which means the typescript compiler will report an error.

Comment: The error happens because of --strictNullChecks compiler option, so I know that for fact, it was just an example in here. I was trying to understand how the whole thing works. Are there any drawback to do compilation first (ts -> js) and use webpack after that to avoid compiling libraries? I suppose I won't be able to use e.g. "angular2-template-loader" then. Still don't know if we can somehow avoid compiling "ts" from angular2

Comment: Using the precompiled version of libraries is the default approach. Especially if you get things from npm, where the libs are mostly precompiled and the entry point for the library (which is described in `package.json`)  points to a .js file or folder. If a precompiled library doesn't also provide the corresponding typings (or it provides them only through another service where versions could mismatch) you could get a worse typing experience than with directly working with a .ts version.

Comment: Debugging might also be worse since you can't the debug the library based on it's typescript code. But this can be also be improved through sourcemaps.

Comment: I did not understand 100% about the precompiled approach, based on the error I provided it definitely tried to compile typescript in angular2, but now when I run the application I get an error in (webpack:///./~/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js?9df7) which means it did what you told: included the whole js bundle. What's the point of traversing the imports if it does that and how did it even find the bundle while it was trying to compile typescript? Maybe there is some guide I can read with explanation of all these tricks?

Comment: There are 2 things going on in parallel: The first is webpack, which includes the included javascript or typescript into the bundle. The second is the typescript compiler, which will also try to get type definitions for all imports and use those to check your code. If you include a js file it will try to resolve the types through an associated .d.ts file which describes what's the content of the module in typescript form.

Comment: Does that mean that `compiler.umd.js` is included by typescript that got it via `.d.ts` file that was in turn triggered by typescript compilation from webpack?

Comment: Not really, the typescript compiler doesn't care about imported js that much. Let's say we have an import statement like `import * as ng2 from '@angular/core'`. The typescript compiler will not look at any js for that but just look up whether **any** referenced .d.ts file defines what the module is about and use that info. For code generation it will rewrite it to a js import. Webpack however will instead really use the referenced .js file and include it in the bundle.

Comment: That seems to make it clearer, so I see that ts generated e.g. this `var core_1 = require('@angular/core');`

Comment: So then we have a two step process: 1. Typescript generates this require statements 2. webpack figures out via node that this `require('@angular/core')` has to be mapped to `@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js`?

Comment: Well, anyway thanks a lot for help, that seem made it clearer. But the whole build system is rather complicated compared to just clicking Build in Visual Studio for C# :)